# How to retrieve same column twice with different values of other column in same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables which are following::

**Village**

```
Village_ID     Village_Name

446261           परसठ्ठी
446262            बम्हनी
446263           लाफिनखुर्द
446264            सोरम
446265             सिधीं
```

**Anganbadi_Master**

```
Anganbadi_ID     Anganbadi_Name     Village_ID
  1307            चिंगरौद             446260
  1308            चिगरौद-2           446260
  1309            बम्हनी-1            446262
  1310            बम्हनी-2            446262
  1311            बम्हनी-3            446262
  1312            लाफिनखुर्द-1         446263
  1313            लाफिनखुर्द-2         446263
```

**Anganbadi**

```
Anganbadi_ID   Food    Month      Year
    1179        हाँ        5        2013
    1309        हाँ        1        2013
    1309        नहीं       1        2014
    1309        हाँ        2        2013
    1310        हाँ        1        2013
    1310        हाँ        2        2013
    1310        हाँ        3        2013
    1311        नहीं       3        2013
    2032        हाँ        3        2013
```

Now I want to retreive food column twice in the basis of two different years, where the same month of different years must appear only once, like following::

```
Anganbadi_ID    Month   food(2013)  food(2014)
1309             1          हाँ       नहीं
1309             2          हाँ       NULL
1310             1          हाँ       NULL
1310             2          हाँ       NULL
1310             3          हाँ       NULL
1311             3          नहीं      NULL
```

But, when I'm trying this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT Anganbadi.Anganbadi_ID
      , Anganbadi.Month
      , Anganbadi.Food  AS food2013
      , NULL            AS Food2014
  FROM Anganbadi
       INNER JOIN Anganbadi_Master ON  Anganbadi.Anganbadi_ID = Anganbadi_Master.Anganbadi_ID
       INNER JOIN Village ON  Anganbadi_Master.Village_ID = Village.Village_ID
 WHERE  (Anganbadi.Year = 2013)
   AND (Anganbadi_Master.Village_ID = 446262)
UNION ALL
SELECT Anganbadi_1.Anganbadi_ID
      , Anganbadi_1.Month
      , NULL                        AS food2013
      , Anganbadi_1.Food            AS Food2014
  FROM Anganbadi                    AS Anganbadi_1
       INNER JOIN Anganbadi_Master  AS Anganbadi_Master_1 ON  Anganbadi_1.Anganbadi_ID = 
            Anganbadi_Master_1.Anganbadi_ID
       INNER JOIN Village           AS Village_1 ON  Anganbadi_Master_1.Village_ID = 
            Village_1.Village_ID
 WHERE  (Anganbadi_1.Year = 2014)
   AND (Anganbadi_Master_1.Village_ID = 446262)
```

It shows following results::

```
 
Anganbadi_ID    Month   food(2013)  food(2014)
1309             1          हाँ       NULL
1309             2          हाँ       NULL
1310             1          हाँ       NULL
1310             2          हाँ       NULL
1310             3          हाँ       NULL
1311             3          नहीं      NULL
1309             1          NULL      नहीं
```

here Anganbadi_ID 1309 showing two different rows for same month (1 ) for year (2013 and 2014)

Comment: The question is already answered on your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423883/how-to-retrieve-same-column-twice-with-different-conditions-in-same-table

Comment: Sahu, you have commented that it is working fine for one of the answers. So, why post the question again? साहू, आप यह जवाब में से एक के लिए ठीक काम कर रहा है कि टिप्पणी की है. तो, क्यों फिर सवाल के बाद?

Comment: @Raj, In previous question, records were finding only basis of Month but Now  I want to find records in the basis of Years which contains same months.
Also in previous question's query I replaced Year in place of Month but the error has occured i.e. "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 SELECT *
  FROM Anganbadi
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(food)
    FOR [year] IN([2013],[2014])
   ) AS p
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5923/4)

```
    | ANGANBADI_ID | MONTH | 2013 |   2014 |
----------------------------------------
|         1309 |     1 |  हाँ |   नहीं |
|         1310 |     1 |  हाँ | (null) |
|         1309 |     2 |  हाँ | (null) |
|         1310 |     2 |  हाँ | (null) |
|         1310 |     3 |  हाँ | (null) |
|         1311 |     3 | नहीं | (null) |
|         2032 |     3 |  हाँ | (null) |
|         1179 |     5 |  हाँ | (null) |
```

Comment: No, it is not working properly. Plz give me other solution

Comment: What is not correct ?

Comment: Same Anganbadi_ID showing two different rows for same month (1 ) for year (2013 and 2014)...and I've already tried same thing in my above query....Sir please give me code for my above requested result.

Comment: sir, please give me a solution to find that without using PIVOT Because I want to compare all the columns in the Table Anganbadi in the basis of two different years and i can't understand how to handle it by using PIVOT.

Comment: I cannot see any two with same `ANGANBADI_ID` and `MONTH`. What is wrong in this output ?